# Consider the linear function F, Is $ F $ uniformly continuous? Find what is requested.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Consider the linear function

$$F (X) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 5 \\
5 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find a number $ c $ such that $ || F (X) || \leq c || X || $.

Find a number $ d $ such that $ || F (X) -F (Y) || \leq d || X-Y || $.

Is $ F $ uniformly continuous?

I have the following:

$$ F (X) = \begin{pmatrix}
5x_2-x_1 \\
5x_1-x_2
\end{pmatrix} $$ then $ || F (X) || = \sqrt {26x_2 ^ 2-20x_1x_2 + 26x_1 ^ 2} $. I guess we should consider $Y=\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix}$, then $$F(X)-F(Y)=\begin{pmatrix}
-x_1+5x_2+y_1-5y_2 \\
5x_1-x_2-5y_1+y_2
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$||F(X)-F(Y)||=\sqrt{26x_1^2-20x_1x_2-52x_1y_1+20x_1y_2+26x_2^2+26y_1^2+20x_2y_1+26y_2^2-52x_2y_2-20y_1y_2}$$
We also have $X-Y=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-y_1 \\
x_2-y_2
\end{pmatrix}$  $$||X-Y||=\sqrt{x_1^2-2x_1y_1+y_1^2+x_2^2-2x_2y_2+y_2^2}$$

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that actually describes the core of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making things pretty hard on yourself. For one, $F$ is linear so you can just take $d = c$. Indeed, $||F(X) - F(Y)|| = ||F(X - Y)|| \leq c ||X - Y||$.

Additionally, note that for nonzero vectors $X$, the desired inequality is equivalent to $\frac{||F(X)||}{||X||} \leq c$, and $\frac{||F(X)||}{||X||} = \left|\left|F\left(\frac{X}{||X||}\right)\right|\right|$. The vector $\frac{X}{||X||}$ has norm $1$, so the condition on $c$ we need is that $||F(u)|| \leq c$ for all $||u|| = 1$. Now, there is an abstract proof that such a $c$ exists using compactness, but I'll assume you want something more elementary.

Indeed, I'll let $e_1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$, $e_2 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1}$, so that $F(e_i)$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $F$. The proof I'll give will, by the way, generalize easily to $n \times n$ matrices. Anyways, I'll claim that $c = ||F(e_1)|| + ||F(e_2)||$ works (in general you'd sum over all $e_i$). In this particular case, that means we can take $c = 2 \sqrt{26}$. Indeed, take some vector of unit length $||u|| = 1$. Then in particular, each component $u_i$ must satisfy $|u_i| \leq 1$. Now, we compute

$$
\begin{align*}
||F(u)|| &= ||F(u_1 e_1 + u_2 e_2)|| \\
&= ||u_1 F(e_1) + u_2 F(e_2)||\\
&\leq |u_1| ||F(e_1)|| + |u_2| ||F(e_2)||\\
&\leq ||F(e_1)|| + ||F(e_2)||\\
&= c.
\end{align*}
$$

Hence, $||F(u)|| \leq c$ for all unit length vectors $u$. As discussed above, this means that $||F(X)|| \leq c ||X||$ for all vectors $X$.

As for uniform continuity, we can use our constant $c$. Take an $\varepsilon > 0$ and $X \in \mathbb R^2$. If we have some $Y$ such that $||X - Y|| < \frac{\varepsilon}{c}$ then by the condition on $c$, $||F(X) - F(Y)|| \leq c ||X - Y|| < \varepsilon$. Thus, we can take $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{c}$ for continuity. But this had no dependence on $X$, so $F$ is uniformly continuous.